# HTML - Link to files in a different folder

Tags: html

I am trying to make a clickable link to an HTML doc that is in a different folder than the original doc. I have read article after article and I can't figure it out.

`<a href="hello.html" target="_blank">Hello</a>` 
I understand this fine^ 
Usually, when I'm linking to another file, it is in the same folder as the one I'm currently using so it works just fine.

Please see the path bellow I use on my computer to reach the file I want: 
Desktop>My Folder>Oct 2020>Oct 15

After reading through articles on the subject, I came up with this, but it's not working.
`<a href="file:///C:/Desktop/My Folder/Oct 2020/Oct 15/hello.html" target="_blank">`

Obviously, there is a key concept I am missing here.

Your advice is appreciated!

Comment: Try to use relative (relative path of the file to the html file) paths instead of absolute (actual path of the file in your PC) path. May be you will get the answer here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Comment: on click what you want to show?

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is determine how to get from the folder that contains your HTML document to the folder that contains your original document.

When writing a path from one folder to another, separate each folder with a `/`, and use two periods `..` to go "up" one level in your folders.

For example, in the folders shown below, if you wanted to edit `file1.html` which is in `My Folder` so it contained a link to `hello.html`, you could use a link like this:

```
 <a href="Oct 2020/Oct 15/hello.html">Hello</a>
```

If, instead, you wanted to edit `file2.html` so it contained a link to `hello.html`, then you could use a link like this:

```
<a href="../../Oct 2020/Oct 15/hello.html">Hello</a>
```

Note that we need to go "up" two levels (up to `Nov 2020` and then up to `My Folder`), so we need to use `..` twice.

[image]

Comment: Good Explanation!

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough explanation, my page links correctly now!